# Adding multiple dataframes to compare against genotypes - DATE/LOCATION - geotemporal incidences of SARS2 genotypes

Tags: covid-19, sars-cov-2, python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to reuse some code I have previously used to add extra parameters.
In the initial code, it was used to give a 1/0 counter if a specific mutation was present (first code below)

```
import re
import os
import pandas as pd
import logging
import sys
import csv

root = "C:"

os.chdir(root)

lineages = os.listdir('Lineages')
mutations = os.listdir('Mutations')

for lineage in lineages:
    
    df = pd.read_csv('Lineages/' + lineage).dropna()
    df.columns = ["lineage"]
    df['lineage'] = [x.split('|')[0].split('_')[-1]
                     for x in df['lineage']]
               

    for mutation in mutations:
        
        mutation_df = pd.read_csv('Mutations/' + mutation).dropna()
        mutation_header = mutation.replace(".txt", "")
        mutation_df.columns = [mutation_header]
        mutation_df[mutation_header] = [x.split('_')[-1].split('|')[0] 
                          for x in mutation_df[mutation_header]]
        
        mutation_set = set(mutation_df[mutation_header])
        
        df[mutation_header] = [1 if x in mutation_set else 0
                               for x in df['lineage']]
        
    df.to_csv('Results9/' + lineage.replace(".txt", "") + '.csv',
                 header = True, 
                 index = False)
```

However, I now wish to add extra parameters such as date of sample and location of sample.
The first code produces this type of counter system:

```
lineage,A222V,D614G,E484Q,E780Q,G476S,L18F,N439K,S477,S477N,T478I,V483A
417941,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
417942,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
417944,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
417946,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
417947,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
417948,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
417950,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
417955,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
431011,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

This code is fine and working, but if I try and add the second parameter (date/location) with the following code:

```
import re
import os
import pandas as pd
import logging
import sys
import csv

root = "C:/Users/jones/Downloads/SARSCOV2/"

os.chdir(root)

lineages = os.listdir('Lineages')
mutations = os.listdir('Mutations')
dates = os.listdir('Dates')
locations = os.listdir('Locations')

for date in dates:
            
    date_df = pd.read_csv('Dates/' + date).dropna()
    date_df.columns = ["Date"]
    date_df['Date'] = [x.split('|')[-1].split('/')[-1] 
                       for x in date_df['Date']]
            
    for location in locations:
                
        location_df = pd.read_csv('Locations/' + location).dropna()
        location_df.columns = ["Location"]
        location_df['Location'] = [x.split('/')[1].split('_')[0]
                                   for x in location_df['Location']]
            
        for lineage in lineages:
    
            df = pd.read_csv('Lineages/' + lineage).dropna()
            df.columns = ["lineage"]
            df['lineage'] = [x.split('_')[-1].split('|')[0]
                             for x in df['lineage']]
               

            for mutation in mutations:
        
                mutation_df = pd.read_csv('Mutations/' + mutation).dropna()
                mutation_header = mutation.replace(".txt", "")
                mutation_df.columns = [mutation_header]
                mutation_df[mutation_header] = [x.split('_')[-1].split('|')[0] 
                                                for x in mutation_df[mutation_header]]
        
                mutation_set = set(mutation_df[mutation_header])
        
                df[mutation_header] = [1 if x in mutation_set else 0
                                       for x in df['lineage']]
   
  
            df.to_csv('Results_3/' + lineage.replace(".txt", "") + '.csv',
                 header = True, 
                 index = False)
```

I retrieve this data, where the counting is maintaibned, but the new parameters (DATE/LOCATION) are not added

```
lineage,A222V,D614G,E484Q,E780Q,G476S,L18F,N439K,S477,S477N,T478I,V483A
417941,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
417942,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
417944,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
417946,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
417947,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
417948,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
417950,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
417955,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
431011,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

In short, my end goal is to:

- Add Lineage ID|Location of Sample|DD/MM/YYY|Mutations| -- as the headers
- still maintain the mutation counter
- Use the mutation counter as a guide to determine where and when the genotypes (mutation combinations) arose.

The files where I am retrieving the parameters looks like this also:

```
hCoV-19/Singapore/4/2020|EPI_ISL_410535|2020-02-03

hCoV-19/USA/WA13-UW9/2020|EPI_ISL_413601|2020-03-02

hCoV-19/USA/WA-UW142/2020|EPI_ISL_416680|2020-03-11

hCoV-19/USA/WA-UW143/2020|EPI_ISL_416681|2020-03-11

hCoV-19/USA/WA-UW144/2020|EPI_ISL_416682|2020-03-09

hCoV-19/USA/WA-UW145/2020|EPI_ISL_416683|2020-03-15

hCoV-19/USA/WA-UW146/2020|EPI_ISL_416684|2020-03-14

hCoV-19/USA/WA-UW147/2020|EPI_ISL_416685|2020-03-15

hCoV-19/USA/WA-UW148/2020|EPI_ISL_416686|2020-03-14
```

A very laborious, and poorly explained question; I apologise in advance!

Comment: I have realised an error in my coding - however, this only allows the initiation of the mutation counter. I am still unable to add the extra dataframes. Please see the editted code.

Comment: Would you be able to share two or three of your input files?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fV6wiYKkTngCFOeOwcfl1JGbhpY_VpWrSpGsdTfy-bw/edit?usp=sharing
Lineage A

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qCNtzRI6EV2GNn3BPuP6EtuB5VWkFqgmGuLT4z_XqoY/edit?usp=sharing
A222V Mutation

Comment: Sorry @BastianSchiffthaler I realise those two files may seem lacking. I was in a rush for work while sending these. So the ‘Dates’ and ‘Location’ input files are identical to the ‘Lineage’ files. I merely copied these, as the code didn’t like trying to make multiple separations from the same folder for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify, when I asked you to share some of your files, I meant to share them in a way that I can reproduce your issue from start to finish. You read from at least four different files in a quadruple for-loop and I'm pretty sure your goal could be achieved much more straightforwardly than your current implementation.

Without a reproducible example, I can offer a best-guess on what's happening: you create `date_df` and `location_df`, but after you instantiate them, you never do anything with the objects. Your final write happens from `df`, so you'll need to add those columns, e.g.:

```py
df["Date"] = date_df["Date"][0]
df["Location"] = location_df["Location"][0]
```

The above is just an example, you'll need to make sure the *correct* value gets assigned to your `df` object instead of simply the first one.

Comment: Again, apologies I was late running for work and rather skimmed the post. So would this be implemented before the mutation_set loop or between it? Or before the df[mutation_header]? I assume the latter

Comment: I assumed the latter and it’s worked perfectly? Thanks again!